# How would I make this code more efficient?

Tags: java, performance

```
    public double getRating(long userID, long movieID) {

    double answer = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < ratingLineData.length; i++){
        String[] temp = ratingLineData[i].split("\t");
        if(Long.parseLong(temp[0]) == userID && Long.parseLong(temp[1]) == movieID)
            return Long.parseLong(temp[2]);
    }



    return answer;
}
```

I have formatted lines of data, and so I want to check if the data at a certain spot of those lines is equal to the userID and movieID passed in, and if it is, I'll return the data at the 2nd element. My problem is probably where I split the line of data by the tab key, but I can't think of anything more efficient, possibly using indexOf, but if I use indexOf then it will also show if there is the user's ID or movie's ID in the time stamp, which would be a bad bug. Can someone give me pointers to what would be faster?

Comment: I don't think it will make much difference... And I suggest that you focus on improving the performance of later calls to `getRating` by storing the data in some map during your first query. So that your later queries are blazing fast instead of re-reading from file again and again.

Comment: Does `getRating` get called multiple times during the running of the program?

Comment: can you show us `ratingLineData` array ? this would really help.

Comment: yes the ratingLineData gets called 20,000 times, and its a .data file formatted like "userID\t movieID\t starRating\t timestamp\n". as in its the 4 pieces of data seperated by tab spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I highlight few ways to optimize, there may be otherways also:

```
public double getRating(long userID, long movieID) {

double answer = -1;
String[] temp = null; // Good to assign data outside the loop
int length = ratingLineData.length; // good practice

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    temp = ratingLineData[i].split("\t");
    if(Long.parseLong(temp[0]) == userID && Long.parseLong(temp[1]) == movieID)
        return Long.parseLong(temp[2]);
}

return answer;
}
```

Comment: I don't think
int length = ratingLineData.length; // good practice will make much difference as it is the property , not a function calling ,
if ratingLineData is a String then int length = ratingLineData.length(); should be used outside .

Comment: Also, declaring temp outside the loop isn't helpful as the String[] is *created* once per iteration anyway. Quite the contrary: declaring in the innermost possible context is preferred coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one obvious optimisation, which avoids the additional long -> double conversion :

```
public double getRating(long userID, long movieID) {

    double answer = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < ratingLineData.length; i++) {
        String[] temp = ratingLineData[i].split("\t");
        if(Long.parseLong(temp[0]) == userID && Long.parseLong(temp[1]) == movieID)
            return Double.parseDouble(temp[2]);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Even so, I'd measure it to be sure.

Moving the `String[] temp` declaration outside the loop is unlikely to make any difference because it does not cause an object allocation.

Comment: long - double happens only once. And why not return long when a long is parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (!) that the ratingLineData is well-formed, you could match both IDs as string and convert only the rating, if there's a match. If there are many searches, sorting and binary search would greatly improve matters.

```
public long getRating(long userID, long movieID) {
  String um = userID + "\t" + movieID + "\t";
  for(int i = 0; i < ratingLineData.length; i++){
    if( ratingLineData[i].startsWith( um ) ){
      return Long.parseLong( ratingLineData[i].substring( um.length() ));
    }
  }
  return -1L;
}
```

Comment: I will try this in a few hours since I'm away at the moment, but that seems like it would work well, as the string starts with both of those pieces.. thanks, great idea!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient code for your parsing should iterate all chars only once and shouldn't allocate new memory. In other words, you just need a state machine like this:

```
CharSequence[] ratingLineData = new String[]{"10\t1\t300", "10\t2\t400", "20\t1\t100"};

public double getRating(long userID, long movieID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ratingLineData.length; i++) {
        final CharSequence line = ratingLineData[i];

        long currentUserID = 0;
        long currentMovieID = 0;
        long currentRating = 0;
        int currentColumn = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
            final char c = line.charAt(j);
            switch (c) {
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                    final int digit = c - '0';
                    switch (currentColumn) {
                        case 0:
                            currentUserID = currentUserID * 10 + digit;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            currentMovieID = currentMovieID * 10 + digit;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            currentRating = currentRating * 10 + digit;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    currentColumn++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (currentUserID == userID && currentMovieID == movieID) {
            return currentRating;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

System.out.println(getRating(5, 3));
System.out.println(getRating(10, 2));        
System.out.println(getRating(20, 1));
System.out.println(getRating(20, 2));
```

This example illustrates the following philosophy. If someone is asking for the most efficient code for parsing, the answer is to build a specific state machine.